# Nodejs, не обрабатывает данные JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, requests, postman

Изучаю ноду и вот шаблонный код, но не обрабатывает req.on('data', (chunk)...) :

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const PORT = 3000;

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
let body = '';
console.log(req.url, req.method);
req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk.toString();
    console.log(body);
});
req.on('end', () => {
    const parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log('Parsed body', parsedBody);
    const propsCount = Object.keys(parsedBody).length;
    console.log('Props count', propsCount);
    res.writeHead(
        200,
        {
            'Content-type': 'text/plain'
        }
    )
    .end(`Body from request has been successfully accepted and parsed. It has ${propsCount} props`);
});
});

 server.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Через Postman отправляю POST запрос с JSON массивом, но выходит такая ошибка:

```
Server is running on port 3000
/ POST
undefined:1
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

В чем может быть проблема, пробовал перед parsedBody вывести console.log(body), но там пусто, значит он даже не обрабатывает мой запрос **req.on('data', (chunk) => {body += chunk.toString();}**
Почему???спасите пжлста.[image: скрин1][image: скрин2]

Comment: С curl у меня этот скрипт работает. Как и где глючит postman непонятно

Comment: @AlexeyTen тогда это что-то с моими настройками vscode или nodejs глючит, хз, я уже на этой мелочи так запарился, что уже готов забить.

Comment: @какую версию ноды используете, у меня 16.13.0 LTS , может из-за этого

Comment: Такой тривиальный скрипт вряд ли зависит от версии ноды. Я проверял на 14

Comment: @AlexeyTen тогда не знаю из-за чего, вариантов не осталось, просто не хочет обрабатывать запрос на data

Comment: Ну так проверьте для начала curl или wget

Comment: @AlexeyTen к сожалению, я пока не умею проверять эти вещи

Comment: @AlexeyTen local address указан как ::1 , это ведет к localhost?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131553/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-the-king-arthur).